# C# Additional information: Child list for field select ACCOUNT, n cannot be created

Tags: c#, sql, alias

```
string sqlGrid1 = @"    select a.ACCOUNT, n.AccountKey, n.NoteKey, n.Notes
                        from tNotes as n join tAccount as a on n.Accountkey = a.Accountkey
                        where TransDate = '2/28/2018'";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection([connection string]);

//Populate grid
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlGrid1, conn);

conn.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(sqlGrid1);
adapter.Fill(ds, sqlGrid1);

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = sqlGrid1;
conn.Close();

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.Columns[3].Visible = true;
```

This code works great if I make the query a view in SQL Server instead, but when I run the code as is, I get this error...

> Additional information: Child list for field select ACCOUNT, n cannot be created.

This error is triggered on "dataGridView1.DataMember = sqlGrid1;"

It looks like the table aliases are not translating. I have tried it w/ and w/o the "as" and w/ and w/o using actual aliases (using "tNotes." and "tAccount." and I get the same error.

How can I use joins in C# so I don't have to clutter my DB with a bunch of pointless views?

Thanks for the assist

Comment: did you try writing query without aliases, using full table names instead?

Comment: @ avb  Yes.  It appears that the code gets stuck on the decimal "." (???)

Comment: is 2nd argument in `Fill` suppose to be a table name?

Comment: @ LONG  I use this basic code all throughout my project.  That second argument is always the source sql statement.  It works elsewhere.  This script ultimately fills a datagrid

Comment: The important part that relates your SQL is when you instantiate the SqlDataAdapter. You do not actually need to pass the sql string itself to ds.Tables.Add(), nor do you need to pass it to DataMember. I think you just need those two values to be equal.

Comment: @ Trioj  Does it matter what I pass to these objects?  Do I even need to populate them here?

Comment: In all honesty, it's been awhile since I've been in Windows Forms world, I believe you just need them to be the same. Hopefully someone more plugged into forms comes along, but if I were you, I would try some simple strings and see if it still fails. var ds = new DataSet("Test"); ds.Tables.Add("Test"); adapter.Fill(ds, "Test"); dataGrid.DataSource = ds; dataGrid.DataMember = "Test"; -- if it still fails, then I'm not going to be much more help.

Comment: @ Trioj  Thank you!!  I did not need a value for DataSet() or ds.Tables.Add().  As long as adapter.Fill(ds, "x") and dataGridView1.DataMember = "x" have the same value, it works.

Comment: if you submit that as an answer, I will check it as the answer...